# Python Key. keys

Tags: python, pyautogui

Hey I'm making an autoclicker with pyautogui and I don't know the keys I can put in for the Key. (variables at the beginning) I want to put in left mouse button down. If I just put a key it gives me an error so yeah I can't find this anywhere.

```
import pyautogui
from pynput.keyboard import *
from pynput import mouse
import random
#  ======== settings ========

delay = random.uniform(.03,.22)  # in seconds
resumeKey = Key.f4
pauseKey = Key.f6
exitKey = Key.esc


pause = True
running = True

def on_press(key):
    global running, pause

    if key == resumeKey:
        pause = False
        print("[Resumed]")
    elif key == pauseKey:
        pause = True
        print("[Paused]")
    elif key == exitKey:
        running = False
        print("[Exit]")
mouseLis = mouse.Listener(on_click = on_click)
mouseLis.start()
def on_click(x,y,button,pressed):
    if button == mouse.Button.left:
        pause = False


def main():
    lis = Listener(on_press=on_press)
    lis.start()

    while running:
        if not pause:
            delay = random.uniform(.03,.22)
            pyautogui.click(pyautogui.position())
            pyautogui.PAUSE = delay
    lis.stop()
mouseLis.stop()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: Hello @Snake, welcome to SO.

You are writing about an error. Please add more detailed information:
Which error is displayed? Which key did you press that caused the error?

Answer (score 0):

The mouse needs its own listener, it doesn't have a keybinding for the keyboard as far as I can tell. Something like this: (Found in the documentation [here](https://pynput.readthedocs.io/en/latest/mouse.html).)

```py
from pynput import mouse

def on_click(x, y, button, pressed):
    # do something here

mouse_lis = mouse.Listener(on_click=on_click)
mouse_lis.start()
```

Answer (score 0):

To solve this I just created another function called `on_click` that handled the mouse button presses.

This function was

```
def on_click(x,y,button,pressed):
    if button == mouse.Button.left:
        print("Output")
```

Basically it takes the click and if the button clicked was the left mouse button then it prints the output in the if statement. There are also three other parameters you have to mess around with if you would like.

In your main function add

```
mouseLis = mouse.Listener(on_click = on_click)
mouseLis.start()
```

This creates the actual mouse listener that will then work to listen to the mouse clicks.

At the end of your main function, be sure to include

```
mouseLis.stop()
```

Comment: So I want it to only be active while the mouse is down how do I make pause True when I let go of left mouse button.

Comment: mouseLis = mouse.Listener(on_click = on_click)
NameError: name 'on_click' is not defined Also I get this error

Comment: I cannot see your code but I presume that on_click is probably not defined because of a misspelling in the function name for on_click (also be sure to make that on_click function or else it definitely will give you an error). For checking for a release, inside your on_click function put an if statement to check for pressed. If pressed is true then you know the button was clicked but if it is false then the button has been released. This is specified in the docs: https://pynput.readthedocs.io/en/latest/mouse.html

Comment: mouseLis = mouse.Listener(on_click = on_click)
mouseLis.start()
def on_click(x,y,button,pressed):
    if button == mouse.Button.left:
        pause = False 
The mouseLis line gets me an error

Comment: Without seeing your whole code the only viable reason I could give for this error is that it is defined in the wrong place. It is above your main function as its own separate function correct? The NameError where it is not defined is most likely just because the function has not been correctly defined. The function I wrote above should be defined as a function separate from main just like how on_press is.

Comment: Also be sure to include `from pynput import mouse`. This imports the actual mouse code.

Comment: Ok so the issue is that the lines `mouseLis = mouse.Listener(on_click = on_click)` and `mouseLis.start()` should be in your main function under `def main():`. Put them directly under `lis.start()` and be sure to keep the proper indenting. Also as a note, be sure to indent `mouseLis.stop()`.

Comment: It doesn't give me a runtime error now but it isn't unpausing when I hit lmb